# Zend framework 2 and Doctrine 2 database generation from entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2

Is it possible to generate the database in a modular fashion ? making relations between entities available depending on which modules are loaded ?

**Example Setup**

- Zend framework 2
- DoctrineORMModule
- Doctrine

Modules

- User
- Group

Each module has corresponding entities which they manage. using annotations for database creation and proxy creation.

relation between user and group 1 -> many or 1 -> 1

**Application 1**

uses module user and group

**Application 2**

uses module user but not group.

is it possible to describe a relation between user and group using doctrine annotations that will be removed if a entity is not present ?

remove or add the relation when ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create or ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update is called

Comment: Why would you use the same class? They really are different entities if you have different associations. You could extend the `User` class and define the group relation in a `GroupUser` class.

Comment: Exactly however I was trying to learn if I "could" do it in one (entity) and modify relationships based upon the relationship actually existed in current configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't remove the annotation if a module is not loaded. You rather should look at things differently.

Seen from your setup of application 1 and 2, the user will be installed and group is depending on user. Note that for application 1, user is **not** depending on group. This means the relation is **unidirectional**: a group is aware of its users but the user is not aware of its group. As you said, the relation is also many:many. And surprisingly, Doctrine has an association mapping called [many-to-many, unidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

The only thing is that you can load a user's group only via the `Group`. You cannot do things like this:

```
$user   = $repository->find(1);
$groups = $user->getGroups();
```

The user is not aware of the groups, so it cannot load them. Instead, ask the group repository for the groups:

```
$user   = $userRepository->find(1);
$groups = $groupRepository->findAllByUser($user);
```

This will ask the group repository to find all groups where the given user is related to.